# Sample a proportion of each group, BUT with a minimum constraint (using dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr, sample

I have a population of 6 categories (stratum) and I want in each stratum to take the 10% as a sample. Doing so I take:

```
var = c(rep("A",10),rep("B",10),rep("C",3),rep("D",5),"E","F");var
value = rnorm(30)
dat = tibble(var,value);
pop=dat%>%group_by(var)
pop
singleallocperce = slice_sample(pop, prop=0.1);
singleallocperce
```

with result:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   var [2]
  var   value
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A     -1.54
2 B     -1.12
```

But I want even if in some stratum that the polupation inside them cannot reach the taken sample of 10% to take at least one observation.How can I do it this in R using dplyr package?

**Additional**

Additionally if I want to make proportional allocation sampling (ie with weight proportional to the subpopulation of each stratum  fro example for A the weight will be : 10/30,for B: 10/30,for C:3/30,D:5/30 etc ) keeping the constrain of 1 observation if the subpopulation does not meet that requirement ?

Comment: sample_n( size = max(0.1 * n(), 1) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible approach (note the presence of 20 x A to check two are returned).

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Data (note 20 As)
var = c(rep("A",20),rep("B",10),rep("C",3),rep("D",5),"E","F")
value = rnorm(40)
dat = tibble(var, value)

# Possible approach
dat %>%
  group_by(var) %>%
  mutate(min = if_else(n() * 0.1 >= 1, n() * 0.1, 1),
         random = sample(n())) %>%
  filter(random <= min) |> 
  select(var, value)
#> # A tibble: 7 × 2
#> # Groups:   var [6]
#>   var     value
#>   <chr>   <dbl>
#> 1 A      0.0105
#> 2 A      0.171 
#> 3 B     -1.89  
#> 4 C      1.89  
#> 5 D      0.612 
#> 6 E      0.516 
#> 7 F      0.185
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Weighted version:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Data (note 20 As)
var = c(rep("A",20),rep("B",10),rep("C",3),rep("D",5),"E","F")
value = rnorm(40)
dat = tibble(var, value)

# Possible approach
dat %>%
  add_count(name = "n_all") %>%
  group_by(var) %>%
  mutate(
    weight = n() / n_all,
    min = if_else(n() * weight >= 1, n() * weight, 1),
    random = sample(n())
  ) %>%
  filter(random <= min) |>
  select(var, value)
#> # A tibble: 16 × 2
#> # Groups:   var [6]
#>    var     value
#>    <chr>   <dbl>
#>  1 A      0.339 
#>  2 A      1.77  
#>  3 A     -0.145 
#>  4 A     -0.915 
#>  5 A      0.146 
#>  6 A      0.896 
#>  7 A     -0.407 
#>  8 A     -1.30  
#>  9 A      1.22  
#> 10 A      0.0527
#> 11 B     -0.602 
#> 12 B     -0.432 
#> 13 C     -0.0540
#> 14 D     -1.45  
#> 15 E      1.54  
#> 16 F      0.879
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for answer.Additionally if I want to make proportional allocation sampling (ie with weight proportional to the subpopulation of each stratum  fro example for A the weight will be : 10/30,for B: 10/30,for C:3/30,D:5/30 etc ) keeping the constrain of 1 observation if the subpopulation does not meet that requirement ? You can edit the answer if you like.

Comment: what is the point of `filter(random <= min)`? can we simply `group_by(var) %>% sample_n(min)`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a potential solution:

```
sample_func <- function(data) {
  standard <- data %>% 
    group_by(var) %>% 
    slice_sample(prop = 0.1) %>% 
    ungroup()
  
  if(!all(unique(data$var) %in% unique(standard$var))) {
    mins <- data %>% 
      filter(!var %in% standard$var) %>% 
      group_by(var) %>% 
      slice(1) %>% 
      ungroup()
  }
  
  bind_rows(standard, mins) 
  
}

sample_func(dat)
```

Which gives:

```
  var     value
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 A      1.36  
2 B     -1.03  
3 C     -0.0450
4 D     -0.380 
5 E     -0.0556
6 F      0.519
```

The assumption is that if you are sampling proportionally and do not have any sample for `var`, that the minimum threshold would be sampling one record from `var` (by using `slice(1)`).

Answer (score 1):

**data.table**

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dat) # make the tibble a data.table

dat[, .SD[sample((1:.N), fifelse(.N >= 10, .N %/% 10, 1))], var]
```

**results**

```
   var     value
1:   A -0.040487
2:   A  0.543354
3:   B -1.100892
4:   C  0.998006
5:   D  0.496898
6:   E  0.819967
7:   F  0.629236
```

**data**

```
# Data (note 20 As)
var = c(rep("A",20),rep("B",10),rep("C",3),rep("D",5),"E","F")
value = rnorm(40)
dat = tibble(var, value)
```