# Sample a proportion of each group with propotional allocation, BUT with a minimum constraint (using dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr, sampling

This question is a follow up question from [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72476588/sample-a-proportion-of-each-group-but-with-a-minimum-constraint-using-dplyr)

I have a population of 6 categories (stratum) and I want in each stratum to take the 10% as a sample. Doing so I take:

```
var = c(rep("A",10),rep("B",10),rep("C",3),rep("D",5),"E","F");var
value = rnorm(30)
dat = tibble(var,value);
pop=dat%>%group_by(var)
pop
singleallocperce = slice_sample(pop, prop=0.1);
singleallocperce
```

with result:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   var [2]
  var   value
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A     -1.54
2 B     -1.12
```

But I want even if in some stratum that the polupation inside them cannot reach the taken sample of 10% to take at least one observation.As has been answered previously the correct way is :

```
dat %>%
  group_by(var) %>%
  mutate(min = if_else(n() * 0.1 >= 1, n() * 0.1, 1),
         random = sample(n())) %>%
  filter(random <= min) |> 
  select(var, value)
```

But now additionally I want to make proportional allocation sampling (ie with weight proportional to the subpopulation of each stratum  for example for A the weight will be : 10/30,for B: 10/30,for C:3/30,D:5/30 etc and then the weights w_i to be multiplied with the subpopulation of the stratum ) keeping the constrain of 1 observation if the subpopulation does not meet that requirement.

The proportional allocation scheme is as described below:

```
w = dat%>%group_by(var)%>%summarise(w= n()/nrow(.));w         
dat%>%
  group_by(var)%>%
  summarise(Ni=n())%>%
  left_join(w,by="var")%>%
  mutate(sample_per_group=Ni*w)
```

with result

```
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  var      Ni      w sample_per_group
  <chr> <int>  <dbl>            <dbl>
1 A        10 0.333            3.33  
2 B        10 0.333            3.33  
3 C         3 0.1              0.3   
4 D         5 0.167            0.833 
5 E         1 0.0333           0.0333
6 F         1 0.0333           0.0333
```

the column sample_per_group contains the sample number per group (proportional to the subpopulation number).But I want to keep the constrain of sample_per_group <1 to give me one observation.

How can I do this using dplyr package ?
Any help?

Comment: The proportion you can get as `dat %>% group_by(var) %>% mutate(prop = n()/nrow(.))`, but the logic is not clear for the new sampling

Comment: @akrun I made an edit explaining in R the proportional allocation sampling scheme

Comment: `sample` has an argument `prob` that lets you specify the chance of sampling each observation, but that won't help you here because of "minimum 1 obs' constraint.  I would do this by using `dplyr::group_map` to draw the appropriate sample from within each level of `var`.

Comment: @Limey I don't know how to do that can you help plz ?

Comment: Do you need `dat %>% group_by(var) %>% mutate(w = n()/nrow(.), w = if_else(w <= 0.1, 1, w))  %>% group_modify(~ .x %>% slice_sample(prop = first(.$w)))`

Comment: But, I didn't find the `D` element.  So I was curious

Comment: oops yes that's missing.So it is not right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this should work

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
  group_by(var) %>%
  mutate(w = n()/nrow(.), w = if_else(w <= 0.2, 1, w)) %>%
  group_modify(~ .x %>%
         slice_sample(prop = first(.$w))) %>% 
  slice(if(first(w) == 1) 1 else row_number()) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 × 3
   var    value     w
   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A      0.811 0.333
 2 A      0.363 0.333
 3 A      0.355 0.333
 4 B      0.366 0.333
 5 B     -0.979 0.333
 6 B     -0.809 0.333
 7 C     -0.536 1    
 8 D      1.06  1    
 9 E      0.832 1    
10 F      0.937 1
```

Comment: no because for C must select only one observation and now selects 3 observations

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson the prob condition may need some tweaking or else you can add a `slice` after the `slice_sample`.  I modified it

Comment: For the OP is seems correct but for my dataset it doesn't  work because the column value is character (ie contains names not numbers).Do I have to change something ?

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson in my solution, I didn't use the `value` column anywhere in the code

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson sorry, I didn't understand the case as the solution here was based on the `n()` to calculate the `w` which is used in the `slice_sample` and `slice`

Comment: Look it is correct but the solution doesn't hold for my real case data frame.(it has two columns var and id.Both character with 44 different var and 10500 rows) If I group_by(var) and paste the rest of your solution I take one observation per group so 44 obs.Which is wrong.

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson what is the output from `dat %>% 
  group_by(var) %>%
  summarise(w = n()/nrow(.), w = if_else(w <= 0.2, 1, w))`  It must be related to the conditon applied i.e. `w <= 0.2`, maybe it should be `w <= 0.1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245466/discussion-between-homer-jay-simpson-and-akrun).